# How to download an excel File and PDF file using Jquery Ajax MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, download

I am using MVC Application. I want to download excel file and PDF file using Jquery AJAX.

In View page

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="excelbtn" data-is-pdf="false" >Export To Excel</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="pdfbtn" data-is-pdf="true">Export To PDF</a>
```

Jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Report/ExportReports',
        contentType:"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        data: {
            Parameter1: Parameter1,
            Parameter2: Parameter2,
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function (isSuccess) {
            if (isSuccess.Success) {
                }
            } else {
                alert('Something went wrong. Please try again after sometime...');
            }
        },
        error: function (data, status, e) {
        }
    });
```

In Controller

```
public ActionResult ExportReports(string Parameter1, string Parameter2)
    {
       if (Parameter1 = "PDF")
        {
            DataTable exportData = grid.GetExportData(dataSource);
            MemoryStream pdfStream = gridData.ExportToPDF(exportData, repType);

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + executeRepType + ".pdf");
            Response.BinaryWrite(pdfStream.ToArray());
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            DataTable exportData = grid.GetExportData(dataSource);
            MemoryStream excelStream = gridData.ExportToExcel(exportData, executeRepType);
            //Write it back to the client
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + executeRepType + ".xlsx");
            Response.BinaryWrite(excelStream.ToArray());//.GetAsByteArray());
            Response.End();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

So in controller we are getting the all data but we are not able return into view page.

Comment: why do you need ajax for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this Solution.
In View Page

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export To Excel", "ExportReports", new { isPdfExport = false,Parameter1="_Parameter1" ,Parameter2="_Parameter2"}, new { @class="excelbtn" })

@Html.ActionLink("Export To PDF", "ExportReports", new { isPdfExport = true,Parameter1="_Parameter1" ,Parameter2="_Parameter2"}, new { @class="pdfbtn" })
```

if you want to Change the value of parameter1 and parameter2 dynamically than you can use javascript as describe  below

In Javascript:-

```
$('.excelbtn').attr('href', function () {
        return this.href.replace('_Parameter1', Value1).replace('_Parameter2',Value2);
          });
$('.pdfbtn').attr('href', function () {
        return this.href.replace('_Parameter1', Value1).replace('_Parameter2',Value2);
          });
```

In Controller:-

```
public ActionResult ExportReports(bool isPdfExport,string Parameter1, string Parameter2)
{
   if (Parameter1 = "PDF")
    {
        DataTable exportData = grid.GetExportData(dataSource);
        MemoryStream pdfStream = gridData.ExportToPDF(exportData, repType);

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + executeRepType + ".pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(pdfStream.ToArray());
        Response.End();
    }
    else
    {
        DataTable exportData = grid.GetExportData(dataSource);
        MemoryStream excelStream = gridData.ExportToExcel(exportData, executeRepType);
        //Write it back to the client
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + executeRepType + ".xlsx");
        Response.BinaryWrite(excelStream.ToArray());//.GetAsByteArray());
        Response.End();
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make things a bit more simply with help of tools which are coming out of the box. 
The [System.Web.MVC.Controller.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492897%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) provides you a method which will do exactly what you need using byte array or stream or file path. So instead of this part (and same for pdf)

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + executeRepType + ".xlsx");
Response.BinaryWrite(excelStream.ToArray());//.GetAsByteArray());
Response.End();
```

I would use something like this

```
File(excelStream.ToArray(), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, executeRepType + ".xlsx");
```

And there is no actual need in async request. So you can just use direct link.

Comment: I'm using something like this, but how can I update the View (or refresh the page) after this? For some reason, even without the `Response.End()`, the page stops processing after I write the file.

Comment: Depending on what are you using for the front-end there are couple solutions. The classic one would be to use [@Ajax.ActionLink](http://tinyurl.com/obawefg) with `OnSuccess` [AjaxOption](http://tinyurl.com/m7h7ndy) where you can set javascript function which will be executed after controllersuccesfully process your request. As alternative you can use [@Html.ActionLink](http://tinyurl.com/mgz33gc) and specify id or class attr for it, e.g. `@Html.ActionLink("LinkText","Action",null, new {@id="file"})` and catch click with jQuery, post from code `$('#file').click(function(){$.post(this.href..)})`